# How to make same face copy of cube to other adjacent faces?

Tags: scripting

I have a cube that consists of some text & images on one face. I want to make the same face as the other two sides of the cube as shown in the image. Any solution will be appreciated.

[image: see the image]

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is to adapt the faces in UV editing like this:

[image]

or...as Allen proposed:

choose UV -> Reset

[image]

Comment: If you delete the existing UV and create a fresh one, every face will cover the entire UV space.

Comment: @AllenSimpson: damn...that easy! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Thanks, sir for giving idea to solve. But I want to use an array modifier as the text fields I used are dynamic(text will be imported from a CSV file). But don't configure how to solve?